# Cannot show Crystal Report viewer in web page after deployed to virtual directory

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an ASP.NET application which can view report by crystal report viewer properly.

After that I add a virtual directory in website and move web page files to physical path of the virtual directory.
I found that the crystal report viewer is not shown after website changes.

I have already copied aspnet_client folder from C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ directory to the physical path of the virtual directory.
and I make sure that the following is in web.config

Can anyone advise on this?

Working Environment:

Visual Studio Professional 2012

CrystalReportViewer control
CrystalDecisions.Shared (v 13.0.8.1216)

CrystalDecisions.Web (v 13.0.8.1216)

CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine (v 13.0.8.1216)

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: have you installed crystal report viewer to your virtual machine??

Answer (score 0):

You must install Crystal Reports Runtime

### [You can get it here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) (choose Install Executable - Support Pack 12)